# pandas - add new column to dataframe from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column 'D' to a dataframe like this:

```
U,L
111,en
112,en
112,es
113,es
113,ja
113,zh
114,es
```

based on the following Dictionary:

```
d = {112: 'en', 113: 'es', 114: 'es', 111: 'en'}
```

so that the resulting dataframe appears as:

```
U,L,D
111,en,en
112,en,en
112,es,en
113,es,es
113,ja,es
113,zh,es
114,es,es
```

So far I tried the `pd.join()` method but I can't figured out how it works with Dictionaries.

Comment: This is another example of a question erroneously marked as a duplicate. As a reminder to all users: Just because two questions have the same answers, does not mean they are duplicates. This question should be re-opened. StackOverflow should be a key→value store from problems to solutions. If a question can be solved using an answer from an unrelated problem, please provide that as a new answer, adapted to the specific problem the user is facing, rather than marking the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) and pass the dict, this will perform a lookup and return the associated value for that key:

```
In [248]:

d = {112: 'en', 113: 'es', 114: 'es', 111: 'en'}
df['D'] = df['U'].map(d)
df
Out[248]:
     U   L   D
0  111  en  en
1  112  en  en
2  112  es  en
3  113  es  es
4  113  ja  es
5  113  zh  es
6  114  es  es
```

Answer (score 60):

Here is a simpler way that should work well too:

`df["D"] = pd.Series(d)`

*Note: The dict keys need to be in the DataFrame index for this.*

Answer (score 8):

I got `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` error for EdChum's solution when I try to use index.map()... And I haven't found a way to get index as Series.

So I found another solution to this problem by creating a Series object from the dict object first.

```
new_d = pd.Series(d)
```

And then do the pd.join with the column you like. That may help.