# pandas - map nested dictionary values to dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm going a little further [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794959/pandas-add-new-column-to-dataframe-from-dictionary) previous question about mapping dictionary values to dataframes. I have a simple dataframe df like:

```
U,id
111,01
112,02
112,03
113,04
113,05
113,06
114,07
```

and I want to map on a new column the following nested dictionary:

```
d = {112: {'en': 1, 'es': 2}, 113: {'zh': 1, 'ja': 1, 'es': 2}, 114: {'es': 1}, 111: {'ar': 2, 'en': 1}}
```

taking into account only the most frequent `L` values, i.e. 112:'es', 113:'es', 114:'es', 111:'ar'.

On a simple dictionary case, I can use `df['C'] = df['U'].map(d)`. How can I do the same taking only the previous highest values? The resulting dataframe would appear as:

```
U,id,C
111,01,ar
112,02,es
112,03,es
113,04,es
113,05,es
113,06,es
114,07,es
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd flatten the dict to create a new dict and then you can call `map` as before:

```
In [44]:

max_d={}
for k,v in d.items():
    max_d[k] = max(v, key=v.get)
max_d
Out[44]:
{111: 'ar', 112: 'es', 113: 'es', 114: 'es'}
In [45]:

df['C'] = df['U'].map(max_d)
df  
Out[45]:
     U  id   C
0  111   1  ar
1  112   2  es
2  112   3  es
3  113   4  es
4  113   5  es
5  113   6  es
6  114   7  es
```

Comment: excatly what i was looking for!