# Create multiple, new columns from dict values by mapping against a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

This question is related to posts on creating a new column by mapping/lookup using a dictionary. ([Adding a new pandas column with mapped value from a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216425/adding-a-new-pandas-column-with-mapped-value-from-a-dictionary) and [pandas - add new column to dataframe from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794959/pandas-add-new-column-to-dataframe-from-dictionary)). However, what if I want to create, multiple new columns with dictionary values.

For argument's sake, let's say I have the following df:

```
   country   
0  bolivia   
1  canada  
2  ghana
```

And in a different dataframe, I have country mappings:

```
country   country_id   category  color
0  canada    11        north     red
1  bolivia   12        central   blue
2  ghana     13        south     green
```

I've been using `pd.merge` to merge the the mapping dataframe to my df using country and another index as keys it basically does the job, which gives me my desired output:

```
   country   country_id  category  color
0  bolivia   12          central   blue
1  canada    11          north     red
2  ghana     13          south     green
```

But, lately, I've been wanting to experiment with using dictionaries. I suppose a related question is how does one determine to use `pd.merge` or dictionaries to accomplish my task.

For one-off columns that I'll map, I'll create a new column by mapping to a dictionary:

```
country_dict = dict(zip(country, country_id))    
df['country_id'] = df['country'].map(entity_dict)
```

It seems impractical to define a function that takes in different dictionaries and to create each new column separately (e.g., `dict(zip(key, value1)), dict(zip(key, value2))`). I'm stuck on how to proceed in creating multiple columns at the same time. I started over, and tried creating the country mapping excel worksheet as a dictionary:

```
entity_dict = entity.set_index('country').T.to_dict('list')
```

and then from there, converting the dict values to columns:

```
entity_mapping = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(entity_dict, orient = 'index')
entity_mapping.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

And I've been stuck going around in circles for the past few days. Any help/feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If you have a dictionary that you want to merge into a dataframe, why not convert the dictionary into a dataframe and then perform the merge?  It sounds like you want an alternative method that bypasses `pd.merge()`, but since that seems like the most straightforward way I'm not sure how to provide an answer.

Comment: Using pd.merge() may be the most straightforward case, but I just wanted to make sure there weren't other ways that make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after tackling this some where..I guess pd.merge makes the most sense.