# How to add value to a pandas dataframe column by row depending a key value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with a value c for states

```
stateC =    {
  "Washington" : 3,
  "New York" :  5,
  "Houston":  11,
}
```

and a dataframe:

```
State       b    
Washington  09   
New York    100    
Houston     55
```

I would like to integrate that column based on key value of dictionary in `column c` and also a `column d` that has value in `b/c`

```
State       b    c   d
Washington  09   3   3
New York    100  5   20  
Houston     55   11  5
```

How to do that in pandas?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas - add new column to dataframe from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794959/pandas-add-new-column-to-dataframe-from-dictionary)

Comment: The first part of the question is an exact duplicate of the one above, as for the second part it is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df['c'] = df['State'].map(stateC)
df['d'] = df['b']/df['c']
```

You can create a new column that is identical to the State column, then map the dict. Column d is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: very simple using map. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df['c']=df['State'].map(stateC)
df['d']=df['b'].astype(int).div(df['c'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
df['c'] = df['State'].apply(lambda x: stateC[x]) 
df['d'] = df[['b','c']].apply(lambda x: x[0]//x[1], axis=1)
df
```