# Pandas Dataframe iteration loop keeps loading undefinitely

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe consisting of `UserId` and the `Name` of the badge earned by that person on Stackoverflow. Now, each badge belongs to a particular category such as `Question`, `Answer`, `Participation`, `Moderation` and `Tag`. I want to create a column called `Category` to store the category of each badge.

The code that I have written works well if data is less than 1M users, for more data it just keeps loading. How to fix this?

**Dataframe (badges)**

```
UserId | Name
  1    | Altruist
  2    | Autobiographer
  3    | Enlightened
  4    | Citizen Patrol
  5    | python
```

**Code**

```
def category(df):  
  
  questionCategory = ['Altruist', 'Benefactor', 'Curious', 'Inquisitive', 'Socratic', 'Favorite Question', 'Stellar Question', 'Investor', 'Nice Question', 'Good Question', 'Great Question', 'Popular Question', 'Notable Question', 'Famous Question', 'Promoter', 'Scholar', 'Student']
  
  answerCategory = ['Enlightened', 'Explainer', 'Refiner', 'Illuminator', 'Generalist', 'Guru', 'Lifejacket', 'Lifeboat', 'Nice Answer', 'Good Answer', 'Great Answer', 'Populist', 'Revival', 'Necromancer', 'Self-Learner','Teacher', 'Tenacious', 'Unsung Hero']
  
  participationCategory = ['Autobiographer','Caucus', 'Constituent', 'Commentator', 'Pundit', 'Enthusiast', 'Fanatic', 'Mortarboard', 'Epic', 'Legendary', 'Precognitive', 'Beta', 'Quorum', 'Convention', 'Talkative', 'Outspoken', 'Yearling']
  
  moderationCategory = ['Citizen Patrol', 'Deputy', 'Marshal', 'Civic Duty', 'Cleanup', 'Constable', 'Sheriff', 'Critic', 'Custodian', 'Reviewer', 'Steward', 'Disciplined', 'Editor', 'Strunk & White', 'Copy Editor', 'Electorate', 'Excavator', 'Archaelogist', 'Organizer', 'Peer Pressure', 'Proofreader', 'Sportsmanship', 'Suffrage', 'Supporter', 'Synonymizer', 'Tag Editor', 'Research Assistant', 'Taxonomist', 'Vox Populi']

  #Tag Category will be represented as 0
  df['Category'] = 0

  for i in range(len(df)) : 
    if (df.loc[i, "Name"] in questionCategory):
      df.loc[i, 'Category'] = 1 

    elif (df.loc[i, "Name"] in answerCategory):
      df.loc[i, 'Category'] = 2 

    elif (df.loc[i, "Name"] in participationCategory):
      df.loc[i, 'Category'] = 3 

    elif (df.loc[i, "Name"] in moderationCategory):
      df.loc[i, 'Category'] = 4 

  return df   

category(stackoverflow_badges)
```

**Expected Output**

```
UserId | Name           | Category
  1    | Altruist       |    1
  2    | Autobiographer |    3
  3    | Enlightened    |    2
  4    | Citizen Patrol |    4
  5    | python         |    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a dataframe with more than 1M rows, than you definetely want to avoid `for` loops whenever possible. There is an easier to update your `'Category'` column, like it was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794993/14298880).

In your case, you just need to convert your 4 lists with the badges names to a dictionary matching the badge name to its numerical category, like:

```
category_dict = {
    **{key: 1 for key in questionCategory},
    **{key: 2 for key in answerCategory},
    **{key: 3 for key in participationCategory},
    **{key: 4 for key in moderationCategory},
}
```

And then you can replace all your `for` loops for this command:

```
df['Category'] = df['Name'].map(category_dict).fillna(0)
```

This may not solve your whole issue, but at least will save some time.

Comment: This woeks correctly but has 1 issue. There is another category called `Tag` which has to be set as `0` if the badge does not belong to the other 4 categories. Can you add it to the code as well?

Comment: Sorry, I've read it in your question but I forgot to put it in the code. Just add `.fillna(0)`, since not matching values will be set to `nan` by default.