# How to create multiple new dataframe columns from a nested dict, based on the dict key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794959/pandas-add-new-column-to-dataframe-from-dictionary) question, starting with this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'key':[111, 112, 113, 114],'other_data':[1, 2, 5, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
   key  other_data
0  111           1
1  112           2
2  113           5
3  114           7
```

and I want to map multiple new columns based on the dictionary key and one specified column in the dataframe.

```
d = {
    "111": {
        "en": 4,
        "es": 2
    },
    "112": {
        "en": 1,
        "es": 8
    },
    "113": {
        "en": 0,
        "es": 11
    },
    "114": {
        "en": 2,
        "es": 3
    }
}
```

The expected output dataframe is

```
key,other_data,en,es
111,1,4,2
112,2,1,8
113,5,0,11
114,7,2,3
```

The dataframe is large so I'd prefer to do this in one loop or operation if possible.

I tried various combinations of `map()` and `apply()` but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` from dictionary, transpose and convert index to integers for match `key` column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (need same types):

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(d).T.rename(index=int), on='key')
print (df)
   key  other_data  en  es
0  111           1   4   2
1  112           2   1   8
2  113           5   0  11
3  114           7   2   3
```

Thank you @ThePyGuy for suggesting use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').rename(index=int), on='key')
```

Comment: If the column key contains strings, then just change to rename(index=str)?

Comment: @Pranab - then remove `.rename(index=int)`

Comment: @Pranab - It is index created from keys in dict, if in original dataframe `key` columns are strings then remove `.rename(index=int)`

Comment: I think `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')` would be better rather than creating the dataframe then transposing.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the same data types for the column on which you are planning to merge as this matters in pandas, if that's not an issue and you plan to do it manually then you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

df = df.merge(df1, left_on="key", right_on="index")
df.drop(columns="index", inplace=True)
```

However, if you wish not to change the columns, this is a hacky way. Use pandas concat.

```
df = pd.concat((df, df1), axis=1).drop(columns="index")
```

Output in both the scenarios:

```
   key  other_data  en  es
0  111           1   4   2
1  112           2   1   8
2  113           5   0  11
3  114           7   2   3
```